# Change XML data in place using Ruby and Regular Expressions

Tags: ruby, xml, regex

Here's an example of the data:

```
<animals><name>George</name><description>A big brown fox.</description></animals>
```

It really doesn't get more complicated than that.  I want to modify all text in the elements.  (In this case, encrypt it).

What I've come up with so far is:

```
xml_data.gsub(/(<.*>)(.+)(<\/.*>)(?=<)/, "#{$1}#{$2.encrypt_string}#{$3}")
```

But, it only replaces the last element's text.  So I'm obviously missing something.

I invite any suggestions (including using REXML).  I must use libraries standard with Ruby 1.8.7.

There is no chance of the XML being malformed because I wrote the process that produces it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions for this, use a real parser such as Nokogiri:

```
s = '<animals><name>George</name><description>A big brown fox.</description></animals>'
d = Nokogiri::XML(s)
d.search('//text()').each { |n| n.content = n.content.encrypt_string }
s2 = d.to_xml(:save_with => Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION).strip
```

Assuming of course that you have monkey patched `encrypt_string` into String somewhere.

As far as your regex goes, `(.+)` is greedy and will happily consume `</close_tag>`, you have similar problems with `.*`.

---

If you must use a regex (and it seems that you have choice), then you should tighten up your regex and switch to the block form of gsub to get sensible `$1` and `$2`:

```
xml_data.gsub(/<([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/\1>/) { "<#{$1}>#{$2.encrypt_string}</#{$1}>" }
```

Using `[^>]+` and `[^<]+` keeps you within the tags you want and the `\1` back-reference is an easy to way match the opening and closing tags. For example, using `upcase` in place of `encrypt_string` does this:

```
>> s = '<animals><name>George</name><description>A big brown fox.</description></animals>'
>> s.gsub(/<([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/\1>/) { "<#{$1}>#{$2.upcase}</#{$1}>" }
=> "<animals><name>GEORGE</name><description>A BIG BROWN FOX.</description></animals>"
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  Unfortunately, Nokogiri is not a part of Ruby 1.8.7 standard library, so it will not work for my purposes.

Comment: @galacticfury: Why not add an option to your generator to encrypt while you generate? And why cripple yourself by limiting yourself to the standard library?

Comment: The "generator" is a Filemaker Pro script.  To even get at the command line I have to use the "Do Applescript" script step within Filemaker, and then use the "Do Shell Script" command for Applescript. Escaping the text for each field to pass to the command line in this manner would be nightmarish (if not impossible) with Filemaker. So, I've elected to just call one ruby script instead. Any user needs to be able to run the script from any workstation, thus the need to stick with only standard libraries. It needs to "just work" without needing knowledge of installing gems and what not.

Comment: @galacticfury: I added a regex-only solution that should do the trick as long as the XML really is that regular.

Comment: Accepted your answer because your code greatly helped me to solve my problem with REXML, which is a standard library.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`.*` matches as many characters as possible. "animals>< name>George< /name>< description"

Better to use `<[^>]+>`.

**Edit**
Had to change what .* matches. (wrong format when pasting xml tags...)

Answer (score 0):

Solution with REXML.  Given `xml_path` is a valid path to an xml file

```
require 'rexml/document'
include REXML

xml_file = File.open(xml_path, 'r')
xml_data = Document.new(xml_file)

XPath.each(xml_data, "//*") do |element| 
  if element.text
    element.text = element.text.encrypt_string
  end
end

encrypted_xml_file = File.new("path/to/new/file", 'w')

encrypted_xml_file << xml_data

xml_file.close
```